# How can I use the passed pointer to an array of characters?

Tags: c, oracle-pro-c

I am biginner in C and PRO*C and need some help. I have a structure as below:

```
typedef struct pt_st{
   char (*s_no)[100];
   char (*s)[100];
} pt_st;
```

have a function like c_info which calls post function:

```
int c_info(pt_st ir_st)
{
  int   li_result = 0;
  li_result = post(ir_st.s_no)
}
```

and post function is :

```
int post(char (*s_no)[100])
{
  EXEC SQL FOR 100
  insert into table_1(col1)
  values(values from the array); //I want to read one value each time in the loop and insert
}
```

What should "values from the array" be?!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `s_no` is of type `char (*)[100]` then `s_no[i]` is of type `char*`.

To insert it as an array you can use [Host arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28427/pc_08arr.htm#i1874):

> You can use host arrays as input variables in an INSERT statement.
>   Just make sure your program populates the arrays with data before
>   executing the INSERT statement.
>
> If some elements in the arrays are irrelevant, you can use the FOR
>   clause to control the number of rows inserted. See also "Using the FOR
>   Clause".
>
> An example of inserting with host arrays follows:
>
> ```
> char   emp_name[50][20];
> int    emp_number[50];  float  salary[50]; 
> /* populate the host arrays */  
>    EXEC SQL INSERT INTO EMP (ENAME, EMPNO, SAL) 
>     VALUES (:emp_name, :emp_number, :salary);
> ```

(From docs.oracle.com on PRO*C)

So here I think you can simply use :

```
values (:s_no )
```

If that doesn't work it means you have to specify a size of your string (I'd think you should because your columns are not infinite in size)

Comment: Hi! thanks for your quick reply. what do you mean by something((*s_no)[i]); ?! I have  insert into table_1(col1)
  values(x);  what is x?!

Comment: `(*s_no)[i]` is the value at index `i` in your array.

Comment: but how can I insert it into table_1?! can I say int   x; then for (int i = 0; ....; i++)
{
  strcpy(x,((*s_no)[i]);  exec sql insert into table_1 (col1) values(x);
}

Comment: @Dax I was wrong in my assumptions, I edited my answer and I hope it suits your problem better.

Comment: I wonder if this would work for the "scattered" array described `char (*s_no)[100]`.